# how do i transform between a static and a dynamic coordinate system

Tags: math, geometry, linear-algebra, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

i have a setup like this:

[image]

2 coordinate systems. (x,y) is the main coordinate system and (x',y') is a coordinate system that lives inside (x,y).  The system (x',y') is defined by the points x1 or x2 and if i move these 2 points around then (x',y') moves accordingly. The origin of (x',y') is defined as the middle of the vector going from x1 to x2, and the y' axis is the normal vector on x1->x2 going through the origin. If i have a point x3 defined in (x',y') and i move either of x1 or x2 to make the origin shift place, how do i then move x3 accordingly such that it maintains its position in the new (x',y') ?
And how do i make a transformation which always converts a point in (x,y) to a point in (x',y') nomatter how x1 and x2 have been set?

I was thinking that if i had more points than just the one i am moving (x1 or x2) i guess i could try to estimate theta, tx, ty of the transformation

```
[x2']   [cos(theta) , sin(theta), tx][x2]
[y2'] = [-sin(theta), cos(theta), ty][y2]
[ 1 ]   [    0      ,      0    , 1 ][1 ]
```

and just apply that estimated transformation to x3 and i would be good...mmm but i think i would need 3 points in order to estimate theta, tx and ty right? 
I mean i could estimate using some least squares approach...but 3 unknowns requires 3 coordinate sets right?

I tried to implement this and calculate an example. I hope you understand the syntax. Its not really giving me what i expect:

```
import math
import numpy as np

x1=[ 0,10]
x2=[10,20]

rx = x2[0] - x1[0]
ry = x2[1] - x1[1]
rlen = math.sqrt(rx*rx+ry*ry)
c = rx / rlen
s = ry / rlen


dx = - ( x1[0] + x2[0] )/2 # changing the sign to be negative seems to 
dy = - ( x1[1] + x2[1] )/2 # rectify translation. Rotation still is wrong

M = np.array([[c, -s, 0],[s, c, 0],[dx, dy, 1]])
print( np.dot(x2 + [1],M) )
# Yields -> [ 15.92031022  -8.63603897   1.        ] and should yield [5,0,1]
```

Since I am trying to transform the x2 coordinate, should the result then not have the value 0 in the y-component since its located in the x-axis?

Ok, I tried doing the implementation for x3 from dynamic1 to dynamic2 which the check is that x3 should end up with the same coordinate in both d1 and d2. I did that as you suggested, but I do not get the same coordinate in both d1 and d2. Did i misunderstand something?

```
import math
import numpy as np

x1=[ 1,1]
x2=[ 7,9]

x3=[4,3]

rx = (x2[0] - x1[0])
ry = (x2[1] - x1[1])
rlen = math.sqrt( rx*rx + ry*ry )
c = rx / rlen
s = ry / rlen


dx =  ( x1[0] + x2[0] )/2
dy =  ( x1[1] + x2[1] )/2

M = np.array([[c, -s, 0],[s, c, 0],[-dx*c-dy*s, dx*s-dy*c, 1]])
Minv = np.array([[c, s, 0],[-s, c, 0],[dx, dy, 1]])


x1new=[ 1,1]
x2new=[ 17,4]

rxnew = (x2new[0] - x1new[0])
rynew = (x2new[1] - x1new[1])
rlennew = math.sqrt( rxnew*rxnew + rynew*rynew )
cnew = rxnew / rlennew
snew = rynew / rlennew


dxnew =  ( x1new[0] + x2new[0] )/2
dynew =  ( x1new[1] + x2new[1] )/2

Mnew = np.array([[cnew, -snew, 0],[snew, cnew, 0],[-dxnew*cnew-dynew*snew, dxnew*snew-dynew*cnew, 1]])
Mnewinv = np.array([[cnew, snew, 0],[-snew, cnew, 0],[dxnew, dynew, 1]])

M_dyn1_to_dyn2 = np.dot(Minv,Mnew)

print( np.dot(x3 + [1], M) )
print( np.dot(x3 + [1], M_dyn1_to_dyn2))
#yields these 2 outputs which should be the same:
[-1.6 -1.2  1. ]
[-3.53219692  8.29298408  1.        ]
```

Comment: you can try double dimension array to save it  dan easily change its value

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Im not sure I quite follow you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit. Matrix correction.

To translate coordinates from static system to `(x1,x2)` defined one, you have to apply affine transformation.
Matrix of this transformation `M` consists of shift matrix `S` and rotation about origin `R`.

Matrix `M` is combination of `S` and `R`:

```
      c            -s          0
M =   s             c          0
      -dx*c-dy*s   dx*s-dy*c   1
```

Here `c` and `s` are cosine and sine of rotation angle, their values are respectively `x-` and `y-` components of unit (normalized) vector `x1x2`.

```
rx = x2.x - x1.x
ry = x2.y - x1.y
len = Sqrt(rx*rx+ry*ry)
c = rx / Len
s = ry / Len
```

And shift components:

```
dx = (x1.x + x2.x)/2
dy = (x1.y + x2.y)/2
```

To translate (xx,yy) coordinates from static system to rotate one, we have to find

```
xx' = xx*c+yy*s-dx*c-dy*s =   c*(xx-dx) + s*(yy-dy)
yy' = -xx*s+yy*c+dx*s-dy*c = -s*(xx-dx) + c*(yy-dy)
```

Quick check:

```
X1 = (1,1)
X2 = (7,9) 
dx = 4
dy = 5
rx = 6
ry = 8
Len = 10
c = 0.6
s = 0.8

for point (4,5):
xx-dx = 0
yy-dy = 0
xx',yy' = (0, 0) - right

for point X2 =(7,9):
xx-dx = 3
yy-dy = 4
xx' = 0.6*3 + 0.8*4 = 5   -right
yy' = -0.8*3 + 0.6*4 = 0  -right
```

P.S. Note that matrix to transform dyn.coordinates to static ones is inverse of `M` and it is simpler:

```
       c   s   0
 M' =  -s  c   0
       dx  dy  1
```

P.P.S. You need three pairs of corresponding points to define general affine transformations. It seems here you don't need scaling and sheer, so you may determine needed transform with your x1,x2 points

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I understand as you explained how to do the actual transformation from static system to (x1,x2) defined one. But i did not understand how to find c and s in your transformation matrix. Can you re-elaborate that a bit? You write its x and y component of unit vector x1x2, so is that vector x2-x1 or how do i find that?

Comment: Yes, it is vector x2 - x1, then you need to normalize it (divide components by vector length)

Comment: I tried making an example (I put the code in my original post in top of the page) It does not really seem to give the right result. Did I do some mistake?

Comment: Seems as my mistake. It is needed to check thoroughly matrices and its multiplication order. Probably tomorrow.

Comment: hmm yes....also when i try to set x1=[5,0] and x2=[10,0] then i would expect the output to be [2.5,0] if i tried to transform x2=[10,0] but I seem to get [ 17.5   0. ]... There is something fishy going on it seems

Comment: aha... if i multiply dx and dy with -1 it seems to give the right translation...Rotation still seems to be wrong though...

Comment: @plaindev Found my mistakes, corrected, example added.

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to work very nicely! Lets say I now have the coordinates of point x3 on the drawing in both coordinate systems thanks to your transformation, and I now change the (x',y') coordinate system by moving x2, How do I then figure out where I should put x3 in the new coordinate system?

Comment: If you have x3 coordinates in static, then it is simpler to find new translation parameters and apply them. If you want to update dynamic coordinates without static - formulas will rather complex.

Comment: Sorry, I might not have expressed what i meant clearly.
I will always have only 2 coordinate systems...the static and the dynamic defined by x1 and x2 as discussed above. However I need to map points in the dynamic coordinate system to their new location when the dynamic coordinate system moves by either moving x1 or x2. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. But x1 or x2 moves in static system, and you have to recalculate translation parameters every time. So simple way - two translations  - from old dynamic to static and from static to new dynamic.

Comment: Or you can multiply matrices for old dyn.-stat and for stat-new.dyn and have one matrix.

Comment: mm still a bit confused...sorry that I am a bit thickheaded :) But dont i still need to estimate the transformation for which oldx1->newx1 in the static system such that i can convert x3 to static system, apply same transformation in static system and then transform it to new dynamic system to get coordinates in new dynamic system?

Comment: I edited my initial question again adding an example for how i did the "multiply matrices for old dyn.-stat and for stat-new.dyn" as you suggested, where x3 should have the same value in the 2 dynamic systems...however it does not. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: btw if you want me to put this in a new question I will gladly do this.

Comment: It seems for me that you find M_dyn1_to_dyn2 correctly. But you have to apply `M_dyn1_to_dyn2` to `[-1.6 -1.2  1.]`, not to static x3 coordinates

Comment: hmmm if i do that i get (-4.82221667  1.41287877  1. ) Is that then the static coordiantes for x3 when moved to dynamic2?
If yes...i suppose i should be able to apply Mnew on that output and i should get [-1.6, -1.2] again right? (I dont)

Comment: Yes, coordinates of x3 in dynamic2 system. No, inverse of M_dyn1_to_dyn2 (the same as Mnewinv * M)

Comment: Sorry....I am still confused...I have x3 which is given in static coordinates (4,3) and i transform that to d2 using M_dyn1_to_dyn2. How do I now transform that point to static coordinates?

Comment: between static and dyn2 - Mnew and Mnewinv

Comment: Absolutely brilliant :) Its working like a charm!!!! 
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need double dimension array to save and set your value in that

the structure gonna be like this

```
    =============|========|========|
    index number |x       |y       |
    =============|========|========|
    first point  | [0][0] | [0][1] |    
    second point | [1][0] | [1][1] |                            
    third point  | [2][0] | [2][1] |                            
    =============|========|========|
```

I will use java in my answer

```
    //declare the double dimension array
    double matrix[][] = new double[3][2];

    //setting location first point, x
    matrix[0][0] = 1;
    //setting location first point, y
    matrix[0][1] = 1;

    //fill with your formula, i only give example
    //fill second point with first point and plus 1
    //setting location second point, x
    matrix[1][0] = matrix[0][0] + 1;
    //setting location second point, y
    matrix[1][1] = matrix[0][1] + 1;

    //fill with your formula, i only give example
    //fill third point with second point and plus 1
    //setting location third point, x
    matrix[2][0] = matrix[1][0] + 1;
    //setting location third point, y
    matrix[2][1] = matrix[1][1] + 1;
```

Comment: Sorry. This is not really useful to me. Array dimensioning is not really the problem here. The problem is how to setup a proper transformation.